# Segue out of parent navigation view controller from embedded table view controller

Tags: swift2, xcode7, segue, embed

I have a table view controller embedded in a navigation view controller using `Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller`

Doing that didn't create a Swift file for the Navigation Controller so I created one and assigned the Navigation Controller to that class on the Storyboard.

So I use the Navigation Controller to provide a bottom toolbar (no top navbar shown) to the Table View Controller. On that toolbar, I have buttons that link to other views--views which should not be embedded in the Navigation Controller.

But when I do a basic "Show" segue from my embedded Table View Controller to, for instance, Main Menu controller, we arrive at the Main Menu controller which is now embedded in the Navigation Controller.

I want to segue out of the Navigation controller from its embedded Table View Controller to an unrelated third party.

I've tried using `self.parentViewController` and `self.topViewController` in my `performSegueWithIdentifier` function but those properties aren't found under `self`.

I'm using xcode 7.3.1 (Swift 2).

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you mean in "segue out of ... to "an unrelated third party"" is. I assume if "the third party" is another unrelated view controller, you could probably use self.presentViewContrller.

Comment: I think I was pretty clear what I meant in the two paragraphs preceding the one you quoted from. I tried `self.presentViewController` and it gives me the error that `performSegueWithIdentifier` is not a member of that.

Comment: oh sorry
and I mean self to be table view controller